# Validation in a layered application ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

I'm designing a layered web application with an MVC, Service and Repository layer, however I'm having trouble knowing where to put validation logic that allows me to take advantage of .NET Core built in form validation (eg `ModelStateDictionary`), while following the DRY principle.

The **first** and most obvious approach is to use a `ViewModel` that has the appropriate data annotations:

```
public class VendorViewModel
{

    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }


    public DateTime? VerifiedAt { get; set; }

}
```

Then my controller action would look like this

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] VendorViewModel model)
    {
        await AuthorizePolicyAsync(AuthorizationPolicyTypes.Vendor.Create);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) //Validation problems, so re-display the form.
            return View(model);

        await _vendorservice.CreateVendorAsync(model.Name,model.Phone,model.Email,model.Address,null);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

This works fine, however there are a couple problems:

1. This only supports basic validation such as checking character length, etc. In the particular example above, I want to validate that `model.Address` is a valid address according to google maps and also contains a city that the application is aware of, which means this kind of validation should be moved to the service layer to keep the Controller "thin".
2. The service layer is now missing any validation logic, and assumes that it is always being passed valid data. This seems wrong to me since it seems like the service layer should be responsible for keeping the system in a consistent valid state. A solution to this would be to also add validation logic to the service layer, but that seems to violate the DRY principle in my opinion.

The **second** approach would be to move all of the validation logic to the service layer and move all my data annotations to the actual domain object `Vendor`. This way each operation could validate the model based on the data annotations, and also apply any more complex logic such as validating the address with google maps as previously mentioned. However, I'm not sure how I can validate an annotated object in the same manner that a MVC `Controller` does and pass back a dictionary to the controller. This functionality seems to be specific to MVC and would introduce a dependency on MVC in my service layer which is undesirable.

Is there anyway I can elegantly move validation logic to the service layer while 
taking advantage of data annotations and MVC's built in `ModelStateDictionary`? How do I get the list of errors back to the controller? Do I throw an exception and catch it in the controller if any validation errors occur?

I have seen several questions asking a similar question, but I'm not satisfied with any of the answers. Other answers seem to involve writing validation logic manually and not taking advantage of data annotations. Is this what I should resort to?

Comment: Hi Brad, Did you get a proper response?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom validation attributes in addition to what are available out of the box such as Required,Range,StringLength,etc.
I will provide an example below :

```
public class ValidateAddressAttribute : Attribute, IModelValidator
{
    public bool IsRequired => true;
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; } = "Address is not valid";

    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult>Validate(ModelValidationContext context) 
    {
       List<ModelValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ModelValidationResult>();
       string address = context.Model as string;
       if(!IsAddressValid(address))
       {
         validationResults.Add(new ModelValidationResult("", ErrorMessage));            
       }
       return validationResults;

    }

    private bool IsAddressValid(string address)
    {
       bool isAddressValid;
       //set isAddressValid to true or false based on your validation logic
       return isAddressValid;
    }
}
```

You can now apply this attribute on your address property as follows :

```
[Required]
[ValidateAddress(ErrorMessage="Invalid Address")]
public string Address { get; set; }
```

Comment: Where would I put this? It seems like I would need to put this in the service layer so I can also have the service layer perform validation, but then it adds a dependency to MVC since IModelValidator is defined in MVC.

Comment: I would request you to read [Validating with service layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs) article. It explains wonderfully on how you can create a service layer for validation without taking a dependency on aspnet mvc so that you can reuse this service layer with some other frontend say wpf(imlemented by using a ModelStateWrapper).

Comment: Also, Attributes like [Required] are defined in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and not a part of MVC framework . So , you can use [Validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator(v=vs.110).aspx) class to validate properties that use data annotation in  your service layer if required.